# Shorten some URLs and show them to the user in another format

Tags: joomla-3.x, .htaccess-configuration

I have some sections of my web in joomla that are accessed like this:

http://miweb.com/index.php?option=com_component&view=contracts&ff=1&id=20977&token=8f8c54a3ce165332fd59f17319ba

I want to transform in something like that:

http://miweb.com/index.php?option=com_newname&view=contracts&ff=1&id=20977&token=8f8c54a3ce165332fd59f17319ba

replace the old name with the new one:
com_component --> com_newname

It's possible? How can I do it?

(Edit)

I've tried to edit .htaccess file (mod rewrite) with:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)com_component(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1?%1com_newname%2 [R=302,L]
```

but it does not work well... It shows url local too

Edited: I've tried to modify

```
    public function onAfterRoute()
{
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    $doc = JFactory::getDocument();

    if ($app->getName() != 'site' || $doc->getType() !== 'html')
    {
        return;
    }

    $router = $app::getRouter();

    $uri     = JUri::getInstance();
    $domain  = $this->params->get('domain');

    if ($domain === null || $domain === '')
    {
        $domain = $uri->toString(array('scheme', 'host', 'port'));
    }

    $link = $domain . JRoute::_('index.php?' . http_build_query($router->getVars()), false);

    if ($uri->toString() !== $link)
    {
        $doc->addHeadLink(htmlspecialchars($link), 'canonical');
    }
}
```

in: /plugins/system/sef/sef.php

Comment: Global Configuration >> Enable SEF URL's

Comment: Yes, I have it activated. But for this I think I need to edit the htaccess file with new rule to rewrite

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by overriding the router in the System plugin, either create a new system plugin or add a method in the already existing system plugin that is enabled on your site.

Create the following method

```
/**
 * This event is triggered after the framework has loaded and initialised and the router has routed the client request.
 *
 * @return void
 */
function onAfterRoute() {
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    $input = $app->input;
    $option = $input->get('option', "");

    // will override on the following condition only
    if ($option == "com_component") {
        $input->set('option', "com_newname");
    }
}
```

This will allow you to override all calls to your "com_component" to "com_newname".

You can also override view as per these.

More Info can be found here => https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/System

Comment: the code of the function "onAfterRoute()" in my joomla framework is different. I have tried to add the condition that you have told me but it gives me this error: "Content encoding error" and it doesn't let me enter the page :(

Comment: Please provide your joomla version, also this method can be used in a system plugin only, can you provide the path of file you are adding the code to.

Comment: My Joomla version is 3.4.6. I have edited the question with the code of this function. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Was this method triggered, and if it is and still you are not able to set the new component, try to make changes in the application input  $app = JFactory::getApplication();
$input = $app->input;  as in my example as the option in the input will be used to create the new link